# How to plot different target line for different facet charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have bar charts to plot the revenue for each regions for 12 months' data. The data frame looks like:

```
Month    Region       Revenue
 1       Japan       $1,200.49
 1       France      $71,869.99
 1       England     $28,009.50
 1       Brazil      $54,400.95
```

My code is:

```
Mydata<-read_excel("Revenue.xlsx")
Mydata$Month<-factor(Mydata$Month)

p<-ggplot(data=Mydata,aes(x=Month,y=Revenue,fill=Region))+
  geom_bar( stat = "identity")+facet_grid(.~Region)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 60000,color='black',size=1.4)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar)
```

I set a $60,000 line as the target line, but actually each country has different target line, for example, $2,0000 for Japan, $40,000 for France.

So just don't know how can I achieve this when I use facet_grid

My current charts are:

[image]

Comment: You need another data frame with `x=Month` & `y=target_value_per_country` then add it to your `geom_hline`. You should share your data using `dput()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350230/variable-hline-in-ggplot-with-facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350230/variable-hline-in-ggplot-with-facet)