# Adding horizontal lines to a ggplot-barchart with the value of selected factor-levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this plot

```
df <- data.frame(factor = as.factor(c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3))), Treatment = c(rep(c("A","B","C"),2)), values=runif(6,0,1))

ggplot(df, aes(Treatment, values))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~factor)
```

how can i add a `geom_hline` to each facet with the `yintercept` of a given Treatment-level (e.g. "A")

```
+geom_hline(data=df, aes(yintercept= df[df$Treatment=="A",]))
```

does not work:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6):
>   yintercept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable hline in ggplot with facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350230/variable-hline-in-ggplot-with-facet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(factor = as.factor(c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3))), Treatment = c(rep(c("A","B","C"),2)), values=runif(6,0,1))

ggplot(df, aes(Treatment, values))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~factor) +
  geom_hline(data = df %>% filter(Treatment == "A"), aes(yintercept = values))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).