# ggplot add average line to specific months facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add an "average" line for the month "3" for each year of time series ggplot plots that I have.

I want to draw a horizontal line through the average of the `facets` - I have tried `group_by`, `mutate` etc. but cannot get it working.

Expected output would be just a horizontal line through each of the facets based on that facets months "3" average value.

Code:

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = NO2)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~year)
```

Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(station_location = c("Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", "Pza del Carmen", 
"Pza del Carmen"), date = structure(c(16495, 16496, 16497, 16498, 
16499, 16500, 16501, 16502, 16503, 16504, 16505, 16506, 16507, 
16508, 16509, 16510, 16511, 16512, 16513, 16514, 16515, 16516, 
16517, 16518, 16519, 16520, 16521, 16522, 16523, 16524, 16525, 
16861, 16862, 16863, 16864, 16865, 16866, 16867, 16868, 16869, 
16870, 16871, 16872, 16873, 16874, 16875, 16876, 16877, 16878, 
16879, 16880, 16881, 16882, 16883, 16884, 16885, 16886, 16887, 
16888, 16889, 16890, 16891, 17226, 17227, 17228, 17229, 17230, 
17231, 17232, 17233, 17234, 17235, 17236, 17237, 17238, 17239, 
17240, 17241, 17242, 17243, 17244, 17245, 17246, 17247, 17248, 
17249, 17250, 17251, 17252, 17253, 17254, 17255, 17256, 17591, 
17592, 17593, 17594, 17595, 17596, 17597, 17598, 17599, 17600, 
17601, 17602, 17603, 17604, 17605, 17606, 17607, 17608, 17609, 
17610, 17611, 17612, 17613, 17614, 17615, 17616, 17617, 17618, 
17619, 17620, 17621, 17956, 17957, 17958, 17959, 17960, 17961, 
17962, 17963, 17964, 17965, 17966, 17967, 17968, 17969, 17970, 
17971, 17972, 17973, 17974, 17975, 17976, 17977, 17978, 17979, 
17980, 17981, 17982, 17983, 17984, 17985, 17986), class = "Date"), 
    yvar = c(31, 35, 51, 55, 50, 62, 83, 62, 74, 80, 82, 77, 
    54, 38, 39, 48, 54, 49, 36, 36, 36, 37, 58, 41, 32, 38, 44, 
    57, 40, 54, 69, 70, 57, 48, 45, 35, 33, 39, 46, 46, 43, 50, 
    50, 49, 51, 54, 72, 64, 47, 35, 41, 53, 46, 55, 44, 48, 35, 
    21, 23, 34, 53, 34, 42, 53, 48, 26, 25, 34, 45, 71, 79, 80, 
    59, 31, 30, 43, 44, 45, 58, 65, 59, 43, 33, 29, 37, 50, 48, 
    30, 32, 47, 59, 57, 44, 39, 60, 33, 34, 37, 39, 41, 57, 55, 
    42, 21, 28, 48, 47, 28, 35, 33, 38, 44, 44, 51, 59, 60, 31, 
    39, 55, 47, 47, 28, 20, 30, 56, 49, 34, 13, 22, 16, 18, 34, 
    38, 38, 41, 37, 29, 39, 58, NA, NA, NA, 29, 30, 42, 44, 33, 
    29, 32, 24, 44, 48, 34, 27, 26), year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
    2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
    2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
    2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), 
    month = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
    18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
    30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
    25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
    31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
    26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
    20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-155L))
```

Comment: Something like these https://stackoverflow.com/a/49453699/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/55194736/786542?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding horizontal lines to a ggplot-barchart with the value of selected factor-levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453561/adding-horizontal-lines-to-a-ggplot-barchart-with-the-value-of-selected-factor-l)

Answer (score 8):

You can use geom_smooth, and fit an intercept only line:

```
dat %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = day, y = yvar)) +
geom_line() +
geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~1,se=FALSE)+
facet_grid(~year)
```

[image]

This works because if you fit a linear model, e.g lm(y~1), this is an intercept only model and the intercept will be the mean.

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like this

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(yvar, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = yvar)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = mean), color = "blue") +
  facet_grid(~year)
```

[image]
what I do is to calculate the mean value for each data point that I have with group_by and mutate. then I add one more geom_line layer but this times I set the y aestetic to be the average value instead of.

Hope this helps!!