# variable hline in ggplot with facet: discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to include a hline similar to question ([Variable hline in ggplot with facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350230/variable-hline-in-ggplot-with-facet)) but am having a different issue which I cannot find a working solution to.

```
   p1 <- ggplot(excoretum, aes(x = Indmain...Dis.MutGroup, y = AgeOfOnset)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(data = excoretum, aes(yintercept = "seer_median age of diagnosis")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Age of onset of disease",
                     breaks = seq(0,100, 5),
                     limits = c(0, 100)) +
 scale_x_discrete(name = "Mutation Type",
                  labels = c("Null" = "N", "Missense" = "M", "Unknown" = "U")) +
  ggtitle("Age of onset of the BAP1 extended core tumour spectrum in carriers between mutation types") +
  facet_grid(.~ICD_Grouping) +
  theme_bw()
```

That is my code, I have tried having a separate data frame, I have left_joined the data from the original separate data frame as a column with excoretum. I have made transferred the data from integer to numeric etc but regardless, whenever I try to plot this now.

It returns:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

I can put a singular hline at a value but it won't search out the hline for the facet.

Comment: You should supply bare (not quoted) name of a column for `yintercept`. So use some name simpler then ` "seer_median age of diagnosis"` (maybe `seer_median`) and then use it as `... yintercept = seer_median ...`

Comment: that worked perfectly. That was a much easier fix than expected. Thank you very much @kwiscion